# SQL nested SELECT statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select only certain columns from a table but need to read in these columns based on conditions of other columns that I DON'T want to include in the final output - if that makes any sense. I'm sure it's probably pretty simple but can't see what's wrong.

Hopefully my SQL query will clear up what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT 
    dateOfBooking, amORpm, conferenceRoomID, noDelegates, cateringInfo
    , allergyInfo, specialAccessInfo, bottledWaterNeeded, projectorNeeded
    , lecternNeeded
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.tableBookingSlots
    WHERE bookingID = @bookingID
);
```

Comment: Why do you want a subquery here? You don't need it, it just makes the code harder to read.

Comment: no it makes no sense, add tables and wanted result, which would make everything much clearer

Comment: you missed a table alias after the `)` . Should be `SELECT ... FROM ( . . . ) AS tableAlias;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use CTE in this case

```
    WITH data AS (
        SELECT * FROM  dbo.tableBookingSlots WHERE bookingID = @bookingID
    ) SELECT 
dateOfBooking, amORpm, conferenceRoomID, noDelegates, cateringInfo, allergyInfo, specialAccessInfo, bottledWaterNeeded, projectorNeeded, lecternNeeded
FROM data
```

OR just do it in that way without subquery

```
 SELECT 
dateOfBooking, amORpm, conferenceRoomID, noDelegates, cateringInfo, allergyInfo, specialAccessInfo, bottledWaterNeeded, projectorNeeded, lecternNeeded
FROM dbo.tableBookingSlots WHERE bookingID = @bookingID
```

Comment: A cte makes it even worse.

Answer (score 1):

Your query and pattern is fine, but your subquery needs an alias:

```sql
SELECT 
    dateOfBooking, amORpm, conferenceRoomID, noDelegates, cateringInfo,
    allergyInfo, specialAccessInfo, bottledWaterNeeded, projectorNeeded,
    lecternNeeded
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.tableBookingSlots
    WHERE bookingID = @bookingID
) t;
```